# scroll to next/previous div not working with manual scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently, I'm trying to build a site using jQuery scrolling. My code works but my problem is that using my code, once you've reached the bottom and you manually scroll up, the down button stops working. How do I get the the down button to work, even after manually scrolling to the top?

my current html code :

```
<div class="down">next post</div>
<div class="container">
     <div class="posts"></div>
     <div class="posts"></div>
     <div class="posts"></div>
     <div class="posts"></div>
     <div class="posts"></div>
</div>
```

and my jquery code :

```
var $currentElement = $('.posts').first();
$('.down').click(function() {
    var $nextElement = $currentElement.nextAll('.posts');
    if($nextElement.length) {
        $currentElement = $nextElement;
        $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
            scrollTop: $nextElement.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing')
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: There is no `box` class in your code, can you please specify it ?

Answer (score -1):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/de8t7q6g/1/)...

```
var currentElement = $('.posts').first();
$('.down').click(function() {
  var nextElement = currentElement.nextAll('.posts');
  console.log(nextElement);
  if(nextElement.length) {
      currentElement = nextElement;
      $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
          scrollTop: nextElement.offset().top
      }, 900, 'swing');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: this isn't what i want either, because if you do try to scroll to the bottom and manually scroll up again, it still doesn't work. thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: it only works if you scroll to a random point, not the bottom

Comment: No, when i try to go to bottom and came back manually and click the next post... Its working... I have tried in that fiddle.

Comment: try repeatedly scrolling up after each page jump until it page jumps to the last div, then scroll up. it doesn't work.